# GA Embed API - select Hourly, Day, Week or Month

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I use GA Embed API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/) to have some charts in my website.
I can select date range (start date and end date) for each report.

I want these "Hourly", "Day", "Week", "Month" in my reports charts. I think there must be a parameter for grouping data by time unit, but I can't find it.
How can I add option to select time unit in charts?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely possible with the Embed API, and mostly so out of the box. You just have to explore the various [time dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time) and pick which one you want.

To create an Embed API [`DataChart`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#datachart) instance that shows sessions by hour over the past 7 days, you would do something like this:

```
var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
  'query': {
    'ids': 'ga:XXXX',
    'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
    'dimensions': 'ga:dateHour',
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'yesterday'
  },
  'chart': {
    'container': 'chart-container',
    'type': 'LINE',
    'options': {
      'width': '100%'
    }
  }
});
```